# DAX measures to compare the same period this year to last

Tags: dax, powerquery

I'm trying to use power query DAX language to compare a number of contacts year to date to the number of contacts in the equivalent period from the last financial year. If the data in the table is all of the financial year 2022/23, and month 1-7 of 2023/24, then I want to create a measure to show me months 1-7 of 2022/23.

I've tried to do this by creating a 'YTD period' measure:

```
YTD Period:=CALCULATE(MAX([FY_Month_No]),Query[Der_Financial_Year]="2023/24")
```

and then using that measure to bring back the total

```
Equivalent Period 22/23:=CALCULATE(
    SUM([NumberOfContacts]),
FILTER(
    Query,
        Query[FY_Month_No] <= [YTD Period] &&
        Query[Der_Financial_Year] = "2022/23"
    )
)
```

I want the second measure to bring back 2022/23 total contacts for whatever the most recent month of 2023/24 is, so if it's month 7, then show me the total 2023 month 1-7 (or April-October in other words)

The issue is that the second calculation is returning zero. I think this is something to do with the 2022/23 filter being in there, is the YTD period measure being affected by that filter, and therefore returning no results?

Comment: You know you can specify the last day of the fiscal year when you use TOTALYTD(), right?  TOTALYTD( [numeric column], "6/30" )?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the built in Time intelligence functions available in DAX.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/time-intelligence-functions-dax

In the interim try

```
Equivalent Period 22/23:=
  var fyMonth = [YTD Period]
  RETURN CALCULATE(
     SUM([NumberOfContacts]),
     FILTER(
       ALL(Query),
       Query[FY_Month_No] <= fyMonth &&
       Query[Der_Financial_Year] = "2022/23"
     )
  )
```

Note the ALL(...) - I suspect you may have filters/slicers in play